# Onde armazenar imagens de perfil que o usuário fez upload?

Tags: java, sistema-de-arquivos

Eu tenho um aplicativo JAVA que precisa armazenar imagens de perfil que o usuário enviou.

```
//no meu LOCALHOST eu uso esse caminho e funciona perfeitamente:
File arquivo = novo File("C:/myProject/uploads/profile_images");
```

Então, agora eu quero implantar este projeto, estou usando o ambiente jelastic e a questão é:

**Onde esses arquivos (imagens) devem ser armazenados no Jelastic?**

- Eu já tentei no mesmo código, mas não funcionou.
- Eu já tentei salvar os arquivos na pasta WebContent, funciona perfeitamente, mas quando eu expandir um novo arquivo .war, os arquivos que o usuário enviou serão sobrescritos.
- Eu li sobre salvar arquivos no mySql, é uma boa pratica?

Agradeço a sua atenção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cogitou hospedar na própria máquina? (No sistema de arquivos?) Pois seria um custo mais barato do que o banco, pois este tem o custo por espaço mais alto do que uma máquina.

A melhor solução vai depender do seu contexto, como você falou em tamanho da imagem, acho que o Sistema de arquivos é o mais indicado. Alguns fatos você pode levar em consideração, caso fosse em banco de dados:

1 - O Banco vai ficar (talvez consideravelmente) maior. A solução simples seria servir direto as imagens pelo servidor web(apache e conteúdo estático em diretórios, por exemplo).

2 - Não há controle transacional ou garantia de sincronismo
Você pode apagar o registro no BD e não apagar a imagem (ou o inverso).
Se gravar o registro e houver erro no insert, por exemplo, ficará com uma imagem órfã na pasta.

3 - Aumenta de complexidade do BD, pois agora o backup també mvai ter que considerar a tabela de imagens

Comment: Boa tarde Fernando, Obrigado pela resposta. Então isso é exatamente o que eu queria, gravar no sistema de arquivos, consigo fazer isso com sucesso localmente. Porem no ambiente de produção Jelastic não sei qual o caminho para salvar esses arquivos.

Comment: Sim entendo. Até onde eu sei o Jelastic tem um filesystem de composição que dá pra usar com o docker, ou seja, você vai ter de fato uma máquina alí, aí tem que só ver como faz pra salvar estaticamente as imagens lá. Tem um /home no teu servidor(container) que é possível salvar lá.

Answer (score 2):

Existem certas vantagens consideráveis ao se armazenar as imagens em base de dados ao invés de sistemas de arquivos. Porém o custo de hospedagem de base dados é maior que o custo de hospedagem de arquivos.

Uma análise mais profunda da sua aplicação poderia auxiliar na sua tomada de decisão. Os usuários, quantidade de acessos e natureza das imagens podem lhe induzir a optar por armazenamento em base de dados caso sejam imagens pequenas (menor tamanho, menos gasto com hospedagem - lembra?) por gerar um ambiente de acesso à essas imagens mais controlado que o sistema de arquivos, porém se forem imagens com demanda alta de visualizações, seria interessante optar por hospeda-las em sistemas de arquivos.

Comment: Boa tarde, muito obrigado pela resposta. No meu caso seria imagens ou videos (limitados a 50MB). por isso penso que salvar em base de dados não seria viável, pois 20 videos de 50 MB = 1 GB de espaço.